# Why does my fresh installed Pharo.image does not save as given in the tutorial?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, pharocloud, pharo-5

I am trying to to deploy a Pharo web application on a linux server. I have followed the tutorial in the *Pharo enterprise book*.

However, when I type the command `./pharo Pharo.image save myApp` I get the message `no such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your pharo binary file in the same directory where you are running the command (do you have executable rights)?

From the message I would guess that it can't *find* pharo binary.

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually It was not in the specific directory

Comment: @ludo great.  Please don't forget to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers